c# unity bounds of the array
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HeartManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Image[] hearts;
    public Sprite fullHeart;
    public Sprite halfFullHeart;
    public Sprite emptyHeart;
    public FloatValue heartContainers;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        InitHearts();
    }

    public void InitHearts()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < heartContainers.initialValue; i++)
        {
            hearts[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
            hearts[i].sprite = fullHeart;
        }
    }

}


How can i fix this ?
Youtube, google im still dont know what does this error i am new on c# i am watching tutorials.
Edit: my initialValue looks this:
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


[CreateAssetMenu]

public class FloatValue : ScriptableObject
{
    public float initialValue;
}


Maybe add hearts = new Image[heartContainers.initialValue]; before the for loop?

something looks very weird with a for (int i = 0 ; i < WHATEVER ; i++) loop when WHATEVER is a float - is that the value you meant to use? is it meant to be a float?

yes. i edit my question so you can see and understand more maybe this helps

The array you're iterating - hearts - has a length of hearts.Length; are you sure that heartContainers.initialValue has this same value?
Presumably a trivial fix here is:
var hearts = this.hearts; // (optional) snapshot to allow some optimizations
for (int i = 0; i < hearts.Length; i++) // <== the real change is here
{
    hearts[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
    hearts[i].sprite = fullHeart;
}

If this is meant to already be the same value: you might want to check that, because: it sounds like it isn't.

I think making sure that it is maximum hearts.Length should be enough so maybe simply for(int i = 0; i < Mathf.Min(heartsContainers.initialValue, hearts.Length); i++)

Or even easier fix would probably be just iterate all (i < hearts.Length) and rather do hearts[i].gameObject.SetActive(i < heartsContainer.initialValue);
